# Can't Compile C# Code With "&lt;" and "&gt;" in it

Tags: c#, winforms

The code of this class give some errors most of them on signs like: & and &gt and &lt and only & what could it be ? How can i fix them ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CaptureScreenDirect3D
{
    public static class Direct3DCapture
    {
        private static SlimDX.Direct3D9.Direct3D _direct3D9 = new SlimDX.Direct3D9.Direct3D();
        private static Dictionary&lt;IntPtr, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Device&gt; _direct3DDeviceCache = new Dictionary&lt;IntPtr, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Device&gt;();

        /// &lt;summary&gt;
        /// Capture the entire client area of a window
        /// &lt;/summary&gt;
        /// &lt;param name=&quot;hWnd&quot;&gt;&lt;/param&gt;
        /// &lt;returns&gt;&lt;/returns&gt;
        public static Bitmap CaptureWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            return CaptureRegionDirect3D(hWnd, NativeMethods.GetAbsoluteClientRect(hWnd));
        }

        /// &lt;summary&gt;
        /// Capture a region of the screen using Direct3D
        /// &lt;/summary&gt;
        /// &lt;param name=&quot;handle&quot;&gt;The handle of a window&lt;/param&gt;
        /// &lt;param name=&quot;region&quot;&gt;The region to capture (in screen coordinates)&lt;/param&gt;
        /// &lt;returns&gt;A bitmap containing the captured region, this should be disposed of appropriately when finished with it&lt;/returns&gt;
        public static Bitmap CaptureRegionDirect3D(IntPtr handle, Rectangle region)
        {
            IntPtr hWnd = handle;
            Bitmap bitmap = null;

            // We are only supporting the primary display adapter for Direct3D mode
            SlimDX.Direct3D9.AdapterInformation adapterInfo = _direct3D9.Adapters.DefaultAdapter;
            SlimDX.Direct3D9.Device device;

            #region Get Direct3D Device
            // Retrieve the existing Direct3D device if we already created one for the given handle
            if (_direct3DDeviceCache.ContainsKey(hWnd))
            {
                device = _direct3DDeviceCache[hWnd];
            }
            // We need to create a new device
            else
            {
                // Setup the device creation parameters
                SlimDX.Direct3D9.PresentParameters parameters = new SlimDX.Direct3D9.PresentParameters();
                parameters.BackBufferFormat = adapterInfo.CurrentDisplayMode.Format;
                Rectangle clientRect = NativeMethods.GetAbsoluteClientRect(hWnd);
                parameters.BackBufferHeight = clientRect.Height;
                parameters.BackBufferWidth = clientRect.Width;
                parameters.Multisample = SlimDX.Direct3D9.MultisampleType.None;
                parameters.SwapEffect = SlimDX.Direct3D9.SwapEffect.Discard;
                parameters.DeviceWindowHandle = hWnd;
                parameters.PresentationInterval = SlimDX.Direct3D9.PresentInterval.Default;
                parameters.FullScreenRefreshRateInHertz = 0;

                // Create the Direct3D device
                device = new SlimDX.Direct3D9.Device(_direct3D9, adapterInfo.Adapter, SlimDX.Direct3D9.DeviceType.Hardware, hWnd, SlimDX.Direct3D9.CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, parameters);
                _direct3DDeviceCache.Add(hWnd, device);
            }
            #endregion

            // Capture the screen and copy the region into a Bitmap
            using (SlimDX.Direct3D9.Surface surface = SlimDX.Direct3D9.Surface.CreateOffscreenPlain(device, adapterInfo.CurrentDisplayMode.Width, adapterInfo.CurrentDisplayMode.Height, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Format.A8R8G8B8, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Pool.SystemMemory))
            {
                device.GetFrontBufferData(0, surface);

                // Update: thanks digitalutopia1 for pointing out that SlimDX have fixed a bug
                // where they previously expected a RECT type structure for their Rectangle
                bitmap = new Bitmap(SlimDX.Direct3D9.Surface.ToStream(surface, SlimDX.Direct3D9.ImageFileFormat.Bmp, new Rectangle(region.Left, region.Top, region.Width, region.Height)));
                // Previous SlimDX bug workaround: new Rectangle(region.Left, region.Top, region.Right, region.Bottom)));

            }

            return bitmap;
        }
    }

    #region Native Win32 Interop
    /// &lt;summary&gt;
    /// The RECT structure defines the coordinates of the upper-left and lower-right corners of a rectangle.
    /// &lt;/summary&gt;
    [Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;

        public RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            this.Left = left;
            this.Top = top;
            this.Right = right;
            this.Bottom = bottom;
        }

        public Rectangle AsRectangle
        {
            get
            {
                return new Rectangle(this.Left, this.Top, this.Right - this.Left, this.Bottom - this.Top);
            }
        }

        public static RECT FromXYWH(int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
            return new RECT(x, y, x + width, y + height);
        }

        public static RECT FromRectangle(Rectangle rect)
        {
            return new RECT(rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right, rect.Bottom);
        }
    }

    [System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()]
    internal sealed class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport(&quot;user32.dll&quot;)]
        internal static extern bool GetClientRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

        [DllImport(&quot;user32.dll&quot;)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

        /// &lt;summary&gt;
        /// Get a windows client rectangle in a .NET structure
        /// &lt;/summary&gt;
        /// &lt;param name=&quot;hwnd&quot;&gt;The window handle to look up&lt;/param&gt;
        /// &lt;returns&gt;The rectangle&lt;/returns&gt;
        internal static Rectangle GetClientRect(IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            RECT rect = new RECT();
            GetClientRect(hwnd, out rect);
            return rect.AsRectangle;
        }

        /// &lt;summary&gt;
        /// Get a windows rectangle in a .NET structure
        /// &lt;/summary&gt;
        /// &lt;param name=&quot;hwnd&quot;&gt;The window handle to look up&lt;/param&gt;
        /// &lt;returns&gt;The rectangle&lt;/returns&gt;
        internal static Rectangle GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            RECT rect = new RECT();
            GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rect);
            return rect.AsRectangle;
        }

        internal static Rectangle GetAbsoluteClientRect(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            Rectangle windowRect = NativeMethods.GetWindowRect(hWnd);
            Rectangle clientRect = NativeMethods.GetClientRect(hWnd);

            // This gives us the width of the left, right and bottom chrome - we can then determine the top height
            int chromeWidth = (int)((windowRect.Width - clientRect.Width) / 2);

            return new Rectangle(new Point(windowRect.X + chromeWidth, windowRect.Y + (windowRect.Height - clientRect.Height - chromeWidth)), clientRect.Size);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

On this line for example im getting errors on all the signs like: & and &gt

```
private static Dictionary&lt;IntPtr, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Device&gt; _direct3DDeviceCache = new Dictionary&lt;IntPtr, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Device&gt;();
```

And also on other lines.

How can i fix this errors ?

Comment: Have you considered removing the characters?

Comment: Wherever you got that from, replace `&lt;` with `<` and `&gt;` with `>` and try again.

Comment: And how do i fix this line: [DllImport(&quot;user32.dll&quot;)] im getting an error on the: ";" "&" and the last ";"

Comment: @DoronMuzar: read a book on C# and you'll find your answer there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a result most likely of copying/pasting code from online that was formatted differently or using different encodings, simply <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd> and to find `&lt;` and replace with `<` , as well as `&gt;` with `>`

As for the line in your comment, it should read as `[DllImport("user32.dll")]`, you need to replace `&quot;` with `"`

This will also fix all your `///` comments so you can have proper documentation

In fact, I did all the work for you

```
public static class Direct3DCapture
    {
        private static SlimDX.Direct3D9.Direct3D _direct3D9 = new SlimDX.Direct3D9.Direct3D();
        private static Dictionary<IntPtr, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Device> _direct3DDeviceCache = new Dictionary<IntPtr, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Device>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Capture the entire client area of a window
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Bitmap CaptureWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            return CaptureRegionDirect3D(hWnd, NativeMethods.GetAbsoluteClientRect(hWnd));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Capture a region of the screen using Direct3D
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handle">The handle of a window</param>
        /// <param name="region">The region to capture (in screen coordinates)</param>
        /// <returns>A bitmap containing the captured region, this should be disposed of appropriately when finished with it</returns>
        public static Bitmap CaptureRegionDirect3D(IntPtr handle, Rectangle region)
        {
            IntPtr hWnd = handle;
            Bitmap bitmap = null;

            // We are only supporting the primary display adapter for Direct3D mode
            SlimDX.Direct3D9.AdapterInformation adapterInfo = _direct3D9.Adapters.DefaultAdapter;
            SlimDX.Direct3D9.Device device;

            #region Get Direct3D Device
            // Retrieve the existing Direct3D device if we already created one for the given handle
            if (_direct3DDeviceCache.ContainsKey(hWnd))
            {
                device = _direct3DDeviceCache[hWnd];
            }
            // We need to create a new device
            else
            {
                // Setup the device creation parameters
                SlimDX.Direct3D9.PresentParameters parameters = new SlimDX.Direct3D9.PresentParameters();
                parameters.BackBufferFormat = adapterInfo.CurrentDisplayMode.Format;
                Rectangle clientRect = NativeMethods.GetAbsoluteClientRect(hWnd);
                parameters.BackBufferHeight = clientRect.Height;
                parameters.BackBufferWidth = clientRect.Width;
                parameters.Multisample = SlimDX.Direct3D9.MultisampleType.None;
                parameters.SwapEffect = SlimDX.Direct3D9.SwapEffect.Discard;
                parameters.DeviceWindowHandle = hWnd;
                parameters.PresentationInterval = SlimDX.Direct3D9.PresentInterval.Default;
                parameters.FullScreenRefreshRateInHertz = 0;

                // Create the Direct3D device
                device = new SlimDX.Direct3D9.Device(_direct3D9, adapterInfo.Adapter, SlimDX.Direct3D9.DeviceType.Hardware, hWnd, SlimDX.Direct3D9.CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, parameters);
                _direct3DDeviceCache.Add(hWnd, device);
            }
            #endregion

            // Capture the screen and copy the region into a Bitmap
            using (SlimDX.Direct3D9.Surface surface = SlimDX.Direct3D9.Surface.CreateOffscreenPlain(device, adapterInfo.CurrentDisplayMode.Width, adapterInfo.CurrentDisplayMode.Height, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Format.A8R8G8B8, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Pool.SystemMemory))
            {
                device.GetFrontBufferData(0, surface);

                // Update: thanks digitalutopia1 for pointing out that SlimDX have fixed a bug
                // where they previously expected a RECT type structure for their Rectangle
                bitmap = new Bitmap(SlimDX.Direct3D9.Surface.ToStream(surface, SlimDX.Direct3D9.ImageFileFormat.Bmp, new Rectangle(region.Left, region.Top, region.Width, region.Height)));
                // Previous SlimDX bug workaround: new Rectangle(region.Left, region.Top, region.Right, region.Bottom)));

            }

            return bitmap;
        }
    }

    #region Native Win32 Interop
    /// <summary>
    /// The RECT structure defines the coordinates of the upper-left and lower-right corners of a rectangle.
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;

        public RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            this.Left = left;
            this.Top = top;
            this.Right = right;
            this.Bottom = bottom;
        }

        public Rectangle AsRectangle
        {
            get
            {
                return new Rectangle(this.Left, this.Top, this.Right - this.Left, this.Bottom - this.Top);
            }
        }

        public static RECT FromXYWH(int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
            return new RECT(x, y, x + width, y + height);
        }

        public static RECT FromRectangle(Rectangle rect)
        {
            return new RECT(rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right, rect.Bottom);
        }
    }

    [System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()]
    internal sealed class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern bool GetClientRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a windows client rectangle in a .NET structure
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hwnd">The window handle to look up</param>
        /// <returns>The rectangle</returns>
        internal static Rectangle GetClientRect(IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            RECT rect = new RECT();
            GetClientRect(hwnd, out rect);
            return rect.AsRectangle;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a windows rectangle in a .NET structure
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hwnd">The window handle to look up</param>
        /// <returns>The rectangle</returns>
        internal static Rectangle GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            RECT rect = new RECT();
            GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rect);
            return rect.AsRectangle;
        }

        internal static Rectangle GetAbsoluteClientRect(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            Rectangle windowRect = NativeMethods.GetWindowRect(hWnd);
            Rectangle clientRect = NativeMethods.GetClientRect(hWnd);

            // This gives us the width of the left, right and bottom chrome - we can then determine the top height
            int chromeWidth = (int)((windowRect.Width - clientRect.Width) / 2);

            return new Rectangle(new Point(windowRect.X + chromeWidth, windowRect.Y + (windowRect.Height - clientRect.Height - chromeWidth)), clientRect.Size);
        }
    }
    #endregion
```